# adding a variable into a CASE statement THEN output

Tags: mysql, hadoop, impala

If I have the following code in Impala:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN "MOVE"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN "MOVE"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  ELSE "NOT SHIPPING"
END) AS move
```

and I want the text instead to output something like this:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN "MOVE TO **a3.supplier**"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN "MOVE TO **a4.supplier**"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  ELSE "NOT SHIPPING"
END) AS move
```

how do I code that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` to build the output string:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 < a2.min2 THEN concat("MOVE TO **",coalesce(a3.supplier,''),"**")
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 > a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN concat("MOVE TO **",coalesce(a4.supplier,''),"**")
  WHEN a3.shipped_qty1 < a4.shipped_qty2 AND a1.min1 > a2.min2 THEN "KEEP"
  ELSE "NOT SHIPPING"
END) AS move
```

P.S. I also wrapped the supplier values in a `COALESCE()` since I don't know if those columns can be null, otherwise the query would fail if those values are null.

Comment: concat... why didn't I think of that?  That's way easier than what I was thinking. :)  Thanks man!